# Cannot install Thunderbird on Debian

Tags: debian, thunderbird

So I am running Debian 7.1 and am unable to find any packages for Thunderbird. Does anyone know what has happened to Thunderbird? There are no results in an apt-cache search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debian have re-branded Thunderbird to Icedove (apt-get install icedove). If desired it's possible to download and install the Mozilla version of Thunderbird downloaded from https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/.

Comment: Awesome, that explains a lot!

Comment: This one tiny fact.  Nowhere.